# How can I configure a WiFi proxy that requires a username and password?

Tags: wi-fi, password, proxy

I have an Android 4.1.2 phone, and I need to set a WiFi proxy that requires me to authenticate with a username and password. Where can I setup the user and password for the proxy?

Comment: You could try `user:password@ip-address` for the proxy's server address. Not sure if that always works, but it's worth a try. Let us know if it did, so I write a more detailed answer.

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217801/218526

Answer (score 0):

For some one Google may bring you to this post
On Android 9, Just do as Harshil mentioned (just provide proxy host name and port, then save), when you using Chrome to access internet, there will be a popup to ask for proxy credential, now you can provide your proxy credential

Answer (score -1):

Long press on that wifi connection, tap on show advanced settings. Fill in your details.

The Google Play store, and Whatsapp won't work. For that you'll have to root your phone, and install Proxy Droid or some such proxy app.