# How to set Wi-Fi HTTPS proxy, not HTTP, via adb shell?

Tags: adb, shell, command-line, proxy, https

For HTTP I found a link: [How to set WIFI proxy via adb shell?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98287/how-to-set-wifi-proxy-via-adb-shell)
But I want to setup HTTPS proxy via `adb shell`.

Comment: Which app(s) you want to use proxy with?

Comment: one of our internal application which runs on a special type of android OS hardware where via adb can use the setting and all there is no UI

Comment: Android uses same settings for `http` and `https`. You need to configure your app.

Comment: Can not configure except adb

Comment: sorry what does that mean?

Comment: @IrfanLatifI mean its a different hardware where only adb can work there is no physical UI to set Https proxy. ANd via adb i can only set http proxy

Comment: There's nothing like "https proxy" exists. It's always `http` proxy, just methods are different. For `https`, method used is `http CONNECT` instead of `http GET`. But if the program/app itself doesn't know how to use these methods to create a connection through proxy, the proxy settings we make in Settings UI or on `adb shell` don't make any difference.

Comment: but @IrfanLatif How i can capture traffic over https without https proxy with certificate.please help

Answer (score 3):

This question is a near duplicate of questions like [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/84005/setting-up-an-https-proxy) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69363), and closely related to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208696) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180758). In fact it can be better explained by a developer, but since it keeps on appearing again and again with slightly different situations, I'll try to explain what I know with some unnecessary details to make the picture clear from a broader perspective.

In short:

- Unlike VPN, a proxy - by design - is not meant to be set system-wide. Individual apps have to create connections through proxy instead of connecting directly to remote hosts (visited websites).
- If an app doesn't have built-in support for proxy, it's possible to enforce the proxy on per-app basis or system-wide. Most of the solutions require root access, but Android's [VpnService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService) APIs work without root.

  - Transparently proxying `https` traffic requires SSL Bumping (decryption) on proxy server which breaks the security model of `https`. This needs to be worked around from both sides; client and proxy.

Android lets proxy be configured for Wi-Fi, Mobile Data (APN) or both. As of Android 9 proxy settings are saved in

```
/data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml
/data/user_de/<User_ID>/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db
```

Both files aren't directly accessible for editing without root. But there is another ***Global HTTP Proxy*** setting [meant for](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setRecommendedGlobalProxy(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.net.ProxyInfo)) managed devices which saves proxy information to `/data/system/users/<User_ID>/settings_global.xml`. It's possible to change global device settings through CLI:

```
~$ settings put global http_proxy <host>:<port>
```

And to unset:

```
~$ settings put global http_proxy :0
```

Or you can [manually set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36200703/9165920) keys:

```
global_http_proxy_host
global_http_proxy_port
global_http_proxy_exclusion_list
global_proxy_pac_url
```

Android sets this host/port information as the following Java system properties on all DVMs of running apps:

```
http.proxyHost
http.proxyPort
https.proxyHost
https.proxyPort
```

But only default browser or other system apps necessarily honor these proxy related networking properties. That's why when setting Wi-Fi proxy it warns:

> The HTTP proxy is used by the browser but may not be used by the other apps.

For non-system custom apps, it is up to the app creator to respect the proxy settings and use them for `http` and `https` proxy, as usually a server listening on single port can handle both type of requests (GET and CONNECT) as explained below.

---

### HOW PROXY WORKS (EXPLICITLY)

Actually `http`/`https` proxy is used only by *proxy-aware* apps and Android cannot enforce this system-wide. No one can, except the (`http` client) app which is making `http`/`https` connections. It's because proxy is set on per connection basis i.e. client itself decides which kind of connection it's going to make when creating a network socket. For `http` proxy full URL is to be given after `GET` verb instead of simple path. For `https` proxy the `CONNECT` method is used instead, so that proxy is requested to create a [`http` tunnel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling#HTTP_tunneling) towards remote host, through which TLS handshake takes place (without proxy's involvement) and encrypted traffic flows back and forth. It's essentially like doing a single local port forwarding.

See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209505/218526) for SOCKS proxy. For further details: [Why proxy set on Android does not work when used as hotspot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217848/218526)

### CLIENTS' SUPPORT FOR PROXY

Since establishing a proxy connection is the responsibility of client app, many client libraries have in-built support to configure proxy settings. Mostly web browsers let user configure proxy in settings UI or use system provided information e.g. on Windows there are IE Proxy Settings and also [`netsh`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731131(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#BKMK_2) command for programs which are linked against WinHTTP library. On Linux environment variables [`http(s)_proxy`](https://www.shellhacks.com/linux-proxy-server-settings-set-proxy-command-line) are honored by many networking libraries, CLI utilities and GUI programs including web browsers <sup>([1](https://github.com/himanshub16/ProxyMan/))</sup>.

However native methods aren't directly applicable to Android's Java based framework. Android's `HttpURLConnection` <sup>([2](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), [3](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/12/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html))</sup> and Apache's `HttpClient` (deprecated) handlers honor <sup>([4](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ProxyInfo), [5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html))</sup> above mentioned system properties <sup>([6](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/12/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#Proxies), [7](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/core/java/android/net/Proxy.java#257))</sup>. So the apps making use of these APIs are able to use same proxy <sup>([8](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#proxies), [9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28035322/9165920))</sup> for all connections. An example is WebView <sup>([10](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview), [11](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/ProxyController.html))</sup> which is based on [Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/components/cronet/#quick-start-guide-to-using-cronet):

> by default the system-wide Android network proxy settings are used to redirect requests to appropriate proxy servers

But not all Java libraries consider the VM system properties as was the case with Apache [HttpClient](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1128) before version 4.2. Such apps may listen to `PROXY_CHANGE_ACTION` broadcast <sup>([12](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java#3585), [13](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Proxy.html#PROXY_CHANGE_ACTION))</sup> to get notified of changes in proxy settings and then [getDefaultProxy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getDefaultProxy()) settings - either set through CLI (global) or GUI (per network basis) or programmatically <sup>([14](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration#setHttpProxy(android.net.ProxyInfo)), [15](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LinkProperties#setHttpProxy(android.net.ProxyInfo)))</sup>.

Or app may also ask user to configure proxy in app itself and use multiple available proxies <sup>([16](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ProxySelector.html), [17](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Proxy))</sup> including system properties <sup>([18](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/ojluni/src/main/java/sun/net/spi/DefaultProxySelector.java#59))</sup> on per-connection basis.

Proxy-aware apps, particularly web browsers support:

- Configuring `https` (SSL) proxy explicitly in settings through GUI (e.g. Firefox's `network.proxy.ssl` preference) or CLI (Chrome's [--proxy-server](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/debugging-net-proxy) option) or plugins like FoxyProxy.
- Using `.pac` <sup>([19](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ConfiguringBrowsers#The_PAC_file), [20](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_(PAC)_file), [21](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/secure-web-proxy))</sup> file to import proxy settings from remote host.

  For Wi-Fi APs Android also supports importing `.pac` files (but not WPAD). In this case *ProxyHandler* and *PacProcessor* helper apps make a local proxy available to apps but authentication doesn't work.
- `CONNECT` over TLS connection towards SSL proxy (e.g. [Squid](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS#Encrypted_browser-Squid_connection) or [Apache](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29744)) in contrast to plain TCP `CONNECT` method which sends unencrypted traffic from client to proxy before TLS handshake. See [FoxyProxy](https://forums.getfoxyproxy.org/viewtopic.php?t=1820#p4338) and `network.proxy.proxy_over_tls` option on Firefox.
- Authentication if proxy requires, other apps usually fall back to no proxy mode when connection to proxy isn't established. Apps need to handle authentication even if loading some content in WebView.

So if you want your app to work with `https` proxy, consider all above factors and choose appropriate SDK/libraries when coding the app.

### ENFORCING PROXY (TRANSPARENTLY)

For those libraries and programs which provide no means to configure proxy, there are different methods `proxifiers`/`socksifiers` use to force traffic towards a proxy server.

- [tun2socks](https://github.com/ambrop72/badvpn#tun2socks-network-layer-proxifier) is a socksifier which accepts all TCP (and optionally UDP) traffic directed towards a `tun` interface in routing table. That's how VPN works on Android. While `tun2socks` is a perfect choice to be used with SOCKS tunnels, it doesn't support `http(s)`. But there are `tun2http(s)` solutions (like [TunProxy](https://github.com/raise-isayan/TunProxy)) which are based on Android's VpnService API and transparently redirect all `http(s)` traffic towards remote proxy.
- [redsocks](https://github.com/darkk/redsocks/) is another similar tool but it NATs all traffic to a specific port listening as SOCKS or HTTPS (HTTP/CONNECT) proxy. [`transparent_https`](https://github.com/phinfinity/router_tproxy/tree/master/transparent_https) is another similar custom made minimal solution.

Both above methods can be used on Android to forward traffic to an upstream proxy e.g. on internet or local network <sup>([22](http://blog.dornea.nu/2014/12/02/howto-proxy-non-proxy-aware-android-applications-through-burp/))</sup>. Also see related details in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209505/218526).

- Setup interactive proxy like ZAP or [mitmproxy](https://blog.heckel.io/2013/07/01/how-to-use-mitmproxy-to-read-and-modify-https-traffic-of-your-phone/) on your local network (e.g. on router / gateway) using only routing / TPROXY (no DNAT/SNAT) and configure it to use your [upstream proxy](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-modes/#upstream-proxy) running in explicit mode (`CONNECT`).
- Use Shared library interceptor method. See details in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209505/218526).

### SSL/TLS INTERCEPTION (MITM)

If the purpose of `https` proxy is the Access Control like logging, anti-virus scanning, content blocking, filtering or adaptation, SSL bumping <sup>([23](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS#Intercepting_direct_SSL.2FTLS_connections), [24](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-howmitmproxyworks/#transparent-https))</sup> is required on proxy server. In the [absence](https://milestone-of-se.nesuke.com/en/sv-advanced/server-software/transparent-proxy-2/) of `CONNECT`, the very first HTTP request sent is already encrypted. So the proxy doesn't know who the original intended host is, ([SNI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) may help but even with `CONNECT` method, you can't do [DPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection#Encryption_and_tunneling_subverting_DPI)) without decrypting SSL.

It means that every outgoing SSL/TLS connection is to be terminated and re-established by proxy, so the proxy must be forced intercepting (like [squid](https://tektab.com/2012/09/28/squid-transparent-proxy-for-https-ssl-traffic/)). But not every `https` proxy supports SSL decryption and working transparently <sup>([25](https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy/issues/88))</sup>; the ***s*** part needs [special handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40885184/9165920) of Certificate Authorities. Proxy's root SSL certificate - which signs dynamically forged web server's certificate - [needs to be added](https://nvisium.com/blog/2014/01/10/setting-up-burpsuite-with-firefox-and.html) to credential store of client app and/or device (keeping [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html) in consideration) to avoid [invalid certificate](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/secure-website-certificate#w_problematic-certificates) errors. Or client may opt to ignore the errors, thus defeating the purpose of secure `http`.

If the purpose is not the filtering but only to hide visited websites from ISP / local network or to hide public IP from visited websites, an alternative is to do simple NAT on both sides i.e. on device or router and the remote proxy server. [SSL Pass through](https://portswigger.net/blog/ssl-pass-through-in-burp) is a similar approach.

---

**RELATED:**

- [How to set up a socks5 with Android cli?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209505/218526)
- [Why is not all traffic captured from my device when routing through proxy?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219280/218526)

Comment: This is for Http proxy but i need to setup proxy to capture https traffic where i need to configure proxy of https (with certificate)

Comment: @Manish **SSL/TLS INTERCEPTION (MITM)** is not about `https`? Please go through the answer once, I can't explain everything in comments. Another related answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219280/218526. From which program/app you want to capture traffic?

Comment: I'll go through this document .
An APK is installed in a special type of hardware.

Comment: @Manish you need to build that APK with a proxy-aware `http` client library in order to use proxy. Or otherwise force the proxy as explained in the answer and linked answers.