# Can I access play store via proxy?

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi, proxy

I have an issue with accessing play store when using Fiddler as an inbetween proxy. I have a Unity app which uses http requests as well as purchases via the GooglePlayStore. Chrome browser and in-app http requests work normally. But trying to use the google play store(outside the app) gives me a no-wifi error. In the same spirit also trying to do a purchase from my app also gives me the same error(but other http requests which do download not related to google play work normally).

So my question is basically is it possible to somehow access the google play store through an ssl proxy?(I suppose that would fix my in-app problem). 
This is the setup I followed for fiddler : https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid

I suppose one way would be to filter out

```
android.clients.google.com

googleusercontent.com
```

but ideally I would want to know if this can be achieved without meddling with the proxy server.

Comment: You are doing SSL bump on Fiddler which requires Fiddler's root CA to be part of trusted CAs on Android. But *apps that target API level 24 will—by design—not honor user-added CAs*: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html. So your `https` connections must be breaking. Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217801/218526. You need root access to add a certificate to system's trusted credential store.