# Fix ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED due to a change in global proxy by mobile security framework through adb shell on non rooted phone

Tags: adb, proxy

The problem in a non rooted Samsung Galaxy S7 smartphone:

- ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED in Google Chrome
- No internet access on cellphone wireless settings
- No internet access on cellphone mobile data setting
- only working Whatsapp or Google Duo

Answer (score 3):

**The cause**

- I was working with Mobily Security Framework (https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF). It is a set of tools to analyse mobile apps.
- In the option of dynamic analysis, my cellphone was connected to the PC through USB. The tool works with genymotion emulators (https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/) but if the device is connected, MobSF starts to setup a testing environment in the smartphone.

```
[INFO] Creating Dynamic Analysis Environment
[ERROR] Error Running ADB Command
[INFO] Android Version identified as 8.0
[INFO] Environment MobSFyed Check
[WARNING] This Android instance is not MobSfyed.
MobSFying the android runtime environment
[INFO] Android Version identified as 8.0
[ERROR] Make sure a Genymotion Android x86instance is running
[INFO] Installing MobSF RootCA
[ERROR] Error Running ADB Command
[INFO] Installing MobSF Clipboard Dumper
[ERROR] Error Running ADB Command
[INFO] MobSFying Completed!
[INFO] Starting HTTPs Proxy on 1337
[INFO] Enabling ADB Reverse TCP on 1337
[INFO] Setting Global Proxy for Android VM
[INFO] Starting Clipboard Monitor
[INFO] Getting screen resolution
[INFO] Testing Environment is Ready!
```

- As non rooted device, MobSF fails (`[ERROR] Error Running ADB Command`) but it succedded in changing the global proxy setting (`[INFO] Setting Global Proxy for Android VM`)

**The solution**

- It is explained in [How to set Wi-Fi HTTPS proxy, not HTTP, via adb shell?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217248/how-to-set-wi-fi-https-proxy-not-http-via-adb-shell/217801#217801?newreg=72fb65c56849476b81a9753c022dd701) The command is running in adb shell:

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy :0
```

- In spite of the wifi configuration or mobile data configuration (through APN) is set to proxy none, this global configuration is onlye change through adb shell